# Trying to implement a JQuery script (inexperimented)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a JQuery script to a php file, but so far it didn't work.
I'm very new to web programming (a couple weeks old) and this is my first real use of JQuery.

Here is part of what i want to do with this :
I'm trying to get the opacity of a span element gradually go from 1 to 0 for a login menu. The exact same thing as [here](http://codepen.io/reidark/pen/uAmey).
And this is what i did : /** nevermind, not enough reputation for images **/

I have a some problems with this menu but my priority is to get that javascript to work. It is supposed to reduce the opacity to 0 of the icons in front of "username" and "password" (i'm just trying to have it work on password for now) but it doesn't.

This login form is part of my header.php and going to be all over the website.

Here are my codes (javascript / part of the css / part of my header.php) :

```js
$( "#mdp" ).focusin(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".mdp_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 200);
});

$( "#mdp" ).focusout(function() {
  $( this ).find( ".mdp_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 300);
});

$(".login").submit(function(){
  $(this).find(".submit i").removeAttr('class').addClass("fa fa-check").css({"color":"#fff"});
  $(".submit").css({"background":"#2ecc71", "border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  $(".feedback").show().animate({"opacity":"1", "bottom":"-80px"}, 400);
  $("input").css({"border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  return false;
});
```

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto -15px auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #a6ba89;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 7px
}
input#txt_identifiant, input#txt_mdp {
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0 8px 0 30px ;
 display: block;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
 transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
input#txt_identifiant, input#txt_mdp {
 :-webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
 :-moz-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
#txt_identifiant:focus {
 padding: 0 8px 0 10px ;
 border-color: #a6ba89;
 outline: 0px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6)
}
#txt_mdp:focus {
 padding: 0 8px 0 10px ;
 border-color: #a6ba89;
 outline: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6)
}
.error {
 display: block;
 color: #C85305;
 font-size: 12px;
 min-height: 12px;
}
.placeholder {color: #aaa}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #aaa}
:-moz-placeholder {color: #aaa}

#identifiant {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}
.identifiant_icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    color: darken(#EDEDED, 10%);
    left: 23px;
    top: 18px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#mdp {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}
.mdp_icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    color: darken(#EDEDED, 10%);
    left: 25px;
    top: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- header  -->
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

.......


<div class="bubble">
  
  <form method="post" action="login.php">
  
   <div id="identifiant">
    <input type="text" name="txt_identifiant" id="txt_identifiant" placeholder="username" required="" value="" />
    <span class="identifiant_icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div id="mdp">
    <input type="password" name="txt_mdp" id="txt_mdp" placeholder="password" required="" />
     <span class="mdp_icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div id="maintenir">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_maintenir" id="chk_maintenir"> 
    <label for="chk_maintenir"><span>Stay Connected</span></label>
   </div>
   <div id="soumettre">
    <input type="submit" name="sub_login" id="sub_login" value="" style="" />
   </div>

  </form>
   
</div>
```

And so far when i load my page nothing happens regarding theses icons, while they are supposed to vanish the same way as in the exemple i linked (and i'm guessing the submit button wouldn't either so i didn't bother going farther).

So what did i miss here ?

Thank you ! Any help is appreciated, hope there is enough information and if not i will provide more.

-Apatik

edit1 : my whole script.js looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#mdp" ).focusin(function() {
      $( this ).find( ".mdp_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 200);
    });

    $( "#mdp" ).focusout(function() {
      $( this ).find( ".mdp_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 300);
    });

    $(".login").submit(function(){
      $(this).find(".submit i").removeAttr('class').addClass("fa fa-check").css({"color":"#fff"});
      $(".submit").css({"background":"#2ecc71", "border-color":"#2ecc71"});
      $(".feedback").show().animate({"opacity":"1", "bottom":"-80px"}, 400);
      $("input").css({"border-color":"#2ecc71"});
      return false;
    });
})
```

Comment: Well, it's my first on a programming boards and it seems that the way i added my code i can "run it to try it" and my icon looks to be successfully getting vanished in here, but still not on my website (both wampserver and my free hostinger). I'm confused. still need help ! ^^'

Comment: Try the CSS solution I have posted in my answer to get around needing jQuery for this, as you seem to know your way around CSS it might be best to get to grips with CSS3 animations :)

Comment: Yes, i will try this out as soon as i can, thank you very much ! But still the fact that the script works here in the "code snippet" but not at home really bugs me, i don't quite understand :x

Comment: Try to use this URL for jquery: `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"` - by omitting the protocol it will use the protocol in use by your page (Im assuming your dev server isnt on HTTPS). Also, that loading of jquery _wont_ work on a local file you run from your computer without a server. Google does not allow it over the file protocol.

Comment: If you want to find out why your scripts does not work, add more code. Tell us about your environment (how are you reading this files? Just double clicking them to see them? Or are you using something like MAMP or Vagrant?) - This is all crucial to solve the question

Comment: yes you're right, as another user mentionned i should have put my files online, which i just did : http://apatikgg.16mb.com/  unfortunately i have absolutely no idea what MAMP or Vagrant are for, i just included the script in my <head> </head> balises and also linked the JQuery CND from google, i will also try your previous advice as soon as i get the time to, thank you very much for trying to help :)

Comment: Have a look at MAMP: https://www.mamp.info/en/ - it will run a local server on your computer at and address like `http://127.0.0.1` ("Theres no place like 127.0.0.1!") as if its on the internet, allowing you to test the site properly! Good Luck.

Comment: will do asap, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching an action to an element with the class `login`:

```
$(".login").submit(function(){
    ....
```

But nothing in your html has that class

---

Also, based on your comment where you said it works here but not in your own website, you may well have forgotten to include jQuery library - its done automatically here:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Edit: Your code is in an external file called `script.js` which is fine, but that code executes immediately. It needs to execute once the DOM has loaded, therefore change script.js to look like

```
$(function(){
    // existing code here
});
```

That is a shortened version of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // existing code here
});
```

Either way will ensure your code only executes after the DOM has loaded.

Comment: Hey ! thanks for your answer, yeah the .login is wrong but this is a part of the script that i will edit later, it shoudn't interfer with anything. I do have the JQuery lib included tho, in my header.php

Comment: @apatik do you have a link to your site if its on the public internet?

Comment: let me upload this and it should show up (hopefully) at http://apatikgg.16mb.com/

Comment: Your code needs to be in a `$(document).ready(function(){ // your code here })` inside of script.js - see updated answer.

Comment: what do you mean precisely ? the JS script linked in my first post is all i have on my script.js file :/ Is that where i messed up ?

Comment: @apatik did you see I updated my answer - its hard to be specific in a comment, but essentially just put the contents of script.js inside where ive put `//existing code here`

Comment: Yes, doesn't seems to work tho, maybe i did it wrong, let me add what i end up with in my first post for a better formating (in a minute or so) thanks again for the help

Comment: @apatik can you re-upload script.js?

Comment: sorry i had some duties, i uploaded script.js to the server (i had previously did the test localy on wamp

Comment: holy cow it's working (edit: just making sure everything is allright and i come back to you)

Comment: yep, apparently all my script needed was a Jamiec, thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put focusin/focusout events on inputs not on the parent.

```js
$( "#mdp input" ).focusin(function() {
  $("#mdp").find( ".mdp_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"0"}, 200);
}).focusout(function() {
  $("#mdp").find( ".mdp_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 300);
});

$(".login").submit(function(){
  $(this).find(".submit i").removeAttr('class').addClass("fa fa-check").css({"color":"#fff"});
  $(".submit").css({"background":"#2ecc71", "border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  $(".feedback").show().animate({"opacity":"1", "bottom":"-80px"}, 400);
  $("input").css({"border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  return false;
});
```

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto -15px auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #a6ba89;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 7px
}
input#txt_identifiant, input#txt_mdp {
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0 8px 0 30px ;
 display: block;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
 transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
input#txt_identifiant, input#txt_mdp {
 :-webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
 :-moz-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
#txt_identifiant:focus {
 padding: 0 8px 0 10px ;
 border-color: #a6ba89;
 outline: 0px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6)
}
#txt_mdp:focus {
 padding: 0 8px 0 10px ;
 border-color: #a6ba89;
 outline: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6)
}
.error {
 display: block;
 color: #C85305;
 font-size: 12px;
 min-height: 12px;
}
.placeholder {color: #aaa}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #aaa}
:-moz-placeholder {color: #aaa}

#identifiant {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}
.identifiant_icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    color: darken(#EDEDED, 10%);
    left: 23px;
    top: 18px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#mdp {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}
.mdp_icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    color: darken(#EDEDED, 10%);
    left: 25px;
    top: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- header  -->
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

.......


<div class="bubble">
  
  <form method="post" action="login.php">
  
   <div id="identifiant">
    <input type="text" name="txt_identifiant" id="txt_identifiant" placeholder="username" required="" value="" />
    <span class="identifiant_icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div id="mdp">
    <input type="password" name="txt_mdp" id="txt_mdp" placeholder="password" required="" />
     <span class="mdp_icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div id="maintenir">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_maintenir" id="chk_maintenir"> 
    <label for="chk_maintenir"><span>Stay Connected</span></label>
   </div>
   <div id="soumettre">
    <input type="submit" name="sub_login" id="sub_login" value="" style="" />
   </div>

  </form>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip, but it didn't do the trick unfortunately :( However even if your way might be the right way to write it, it looks like my script the way it is actually work here in my "code snippet" (and also on the exemple link i gave) but i doesn't look to inject in my website

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to solve your problem, and I suggest two ways:

### Javascript

I have simplified your JS to make it work (if I deleted anything of other purposes, well, put that back). I added a class to the group that contains the icon and the input, and then bind on `focus` and `blur` events, like this:

```
$(".fadeicon input").focus(function() {
  $(this).next().animate({opacity: 0})
}).blur(function() {
  $(this).next().animate({opacity: 1})
});
```

I have used the standard `focus` and `blur` events on your input elements, and then select the *next* element to fade in or out. Your icons' HTML now look like this:

```
<div class="fadeicon">
    <input type="text" />
    <span class="mdp_icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
</div>
```

The reason I added a class to the group is so you can easily select *where* you want this to take effect.

### CSS

However, there is an *even better* way that rquires **no javascript**! It is a just css solution and it is two lines long:

```
.fadeicon input + span { opacity: 1; transition: opacity 400ms; }
.fadeicon input:focus + span { opacity: 0; }
```

Again, I used the fadeicon class to make it easily targeted, but as long as you can target them you can do this with CSS!

### Examples

#### Here a jquery snippet:

```js
$( ".fadeicon input" ).focus(function() {
  $( this ).next().animate({opacity: 0})
}).blur(function() {
  $( this ).next().animate({opacity: 1})
});

$(".login").submit(function(){
  $(this).find(".submit i").removeAttr('class').addClass("fa fa-check").css({"color":"#fff"});
  $(".submit").css({"background":"#2ecc71", "border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  $(".feedback").show().animate({"opacity":"1", "bottom":"-80px"}, 400);
  $("input").css({"border-color":"#2ecc71"});
  return false;
});
```

```css
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto -15px auto;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #a6ba89;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 7px
}
input#txt_identifiant, input#txt_mdp {
 border-radius: 3px;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 28px;
 line-height: 28px;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 0 8px 0 30px ;
 display: block;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
 transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
input#txt_identifiant, input#txt_mdp {
 :-webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
 :-moz-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
#txt_identifiant:focus {
 padding: 0 8px 0 10px ;
 border-color: #a6ba89;
 outline: 0px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6)
}
#txt_mdp:focus {
 padding: 0 8px 0 10px ;
 border-color: #a6ba89;
 outline: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 2px rgba(109,157,78,.6)
}
.error {
 display: block;
 color: #C85305;
 font-size: 12px;
 min-height: 12px;
}
.placeholder {color: #aaa}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: #aaa}
:-moz-placeholder {color: #aaa}

#identifiant {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}
.identifiant_icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    color: darken(#EDEDED, 10%);
    left: 23px;
    top: 18px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
#mdp {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 15px 15px 0 15px;
}
.mdp_icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    color: darken(#EDEDED, 10%);
    left: 25px;
    top: 65px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- header  -->
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<div class="bubble">
  
  <form method="post" action="login.php">
  
   <div id="identifiant" class="fadeicon">
    <input type="text" name="txt_identifiant" id="txt_identifiant" placeholder="username" required="" value="" />
    <span class="identifiant_icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div id="mdp" class="fadeicon">
    <input type="password" name="txt_mdp" id="txt_mdp" placeholder="password" required="" />
     <span class="mdp_icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
   </div>
   <div id="maintenir">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk_maintenir" id="chk_maintenir"> 
    <label for="chk_maintenir"><span>Stay Connected</span></label>
   </div>
   <div id="soumettre">
    <input type="submit" name="sub_login" id="sub_login" value="" style="" />
   </div>

  </form>
   
</div>
```

#### Heres the CSS snippet (example):

```css
.fadeicon input + span { 
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms; 
  opacity: 1;
}
.fadeicon input:focus + span { opacity: 0;}
```

```html
<div class="fadeicon">
  <input type="text">
  <span>Fade me out</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, i answered your comment aswell. That's a really great alternative that i didn't know about. However if you check the exemple link i posted i think i may still have to use some javascript at some point, especially for for submit button and a fallback confirmation animation. Also i have to admit that it really annoys not to understand why the script works here in the "code snippet" but not at home...

Answer (score 0):

you use `$( "#mdp" ).focusin(function(){});` on the id `#mdp` but your input field has the id `#txt_mdp`. 
Try this

```
$( "#txt_mdp" ).focusin(function(){ ... });
```

instead.

Comment: thanks for responding, i tried but it didn't work :/ But the script the way it is now seems to work here in the "code snippet" i don't understand why it doesn't on my website :/

Comment: did you change the focusin function to something like this:
`$(this).siblings(".mdp_icon" ).animate({"opacity":"1"}, 300);`

Comment: Hey ! The issue came from my script.js, apparently it didn't have the requiered " $(document).ready stuff and it's now working, the focusin looks fine aswell for now !

Comment: I think you can use defer instead of `$(document).ready` when calling the script like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js" defer></script>` as described [here](http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2014/02/async-vs-defer-attributes.html)